# Convert Nested JSON to Pandas Column

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a Json file as below:

```
[{
'instrument_token': 12335618, 'last_price': 31584.6,
'ohlc': {'open': 31080.1, 'high': 31590.0, 'low': 31049.05, 'close': 31114.7}, 
'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 40, 'price': 31576.4, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 160, 'price': 31576.0, 'orders': 1}], 'sell': [{'quantity': 200, 'price': 31584.6, 'orders': 2}, {'quantity': 60, 'price': 31584.65, 'orders': 1}]}
}]
```

I have tried as below:

```
df = json_normalize(ticks)
print(df)
```

This gives me a result as:

```
  instrument_token  last_price  ohlc.open  ohlc.high  ohlc.low  ohlc.close                                          depth.buy                                         depth.sell
0          12335618     31584.6    31080.1    31590.0  31049.05     31114.7  [{'quantity': 40, 'price': 31576.4, 'orders': ...  [{'quantity': 200, 'price': 31584.6, 'orders':...
```

I want to further normalize the data of **depth.buy & depth.sell** columns in separate columns with column name as:

```
depth.buy.quantity1, depth.buy.price1, depth.buy.orders1, 
depth.buy.quantity2, depth.buy.price2, depth.buy.orders2,
depth.sell.quantity1, depth.sell.price1, depth.sell.orders1, 
depth.sell.quantity2, depth.sell.price2, depth.sell.orders2,
```

Is it possible to normalise further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this example dataset,you can do it like this.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = [{
'instrument_token': 12335618, 'last_price': 31584.6,
'ohlc': {'open': 31080.1, 'high': 31590.0, 'low': 31049.05, 'close': 31114.7}, 
'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 40, 'price': 31576.4, 'orders': 1}, 
                  {'quantity': 160, 'price': 31576.0, 'orders': 1}], 
          'sell': [{'quantity': 200, 'price': 31584.6, 'orders': 2}, 
                   {'quantity': 60, 'price': 31584.65, 'orders': 1}]
          }
}]

df = json_normalize(data)
cols = ["depth.buy","depth.sell"]
for c in cols:
    postdf = pd.DataFrame()
    tmp = df[c].values
    for i,val in enumerate(tmp):
        vals = list(val.values())
        keys = [f"{c}.{k}{i+1}"for k in val.keys()]
        tmpdf =pd.DataFrame([vals],columns=keys)
        postdf = pd.concat([postdf,tmpdf],axis=1)
    df = pd.concat([df,postdf],axis=1)
    df = df.drop(columns=[c])
```

note that,

1. `tmp = df[c].values` take the 0th element of the list.if you have multiple elements you have to loop over the elements.i assumed that all data inside one list.
2. if you need to get column names list (["depth.buy","depth.sell"]) dynamically,you can do it by checking `dtypes` of the `df` and get `object` type column names.